# Replace all double quotes with single quotes

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace all double quotes in a string with single quotes.
here my expression:

```sh
echo "<a href=\"#\" id=\"resendActivationMailLink\">here</a>" | sed "s/\"/'/"
```

unfortunately only the first double quote is replaced :S

```html
<a href='#" id="resendActivationMailLink">here</a>
```

any Ideas?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You need to pass the `g` flag to `sed`:

```
sed "s/\"/'/g"
```

Comment: To help remember this, it's `g` for `global`.

Comment: `echo '"Good morning screwed"' | sed 's/"/\\"/g'`

Answer (score 65):

You could use `tr` here, concise and less of quoting headache:

```
tr '"' "'"
```

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you:

```
sed -i "y/\"/'/" hello.txt
```

`-i` option is used to edit in place on the file hello.txt.

Comment: This outputted the file on the command line, how do you make it change the file itself?

Comment: @JasonBourne you can add the `-i` switch to edit the file inplace i.e. `sed -i "y/\"/'/" file`