# sed usage for ( ' )

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I'm a bit confused on usage of sed regarding substitution of (") double quotes to (') single quote. I tried lot of combinations in sed, but somehow it doesn't allow this particular conversion.

Any assistance will be very much appreciated.

ps: I'm open for other methods of substitution as well, but it should run fine in bash (UNIX)

Comment: What combinations did you try?

Comment: I got my answer here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154007/replace-all-double-quotes-with-single-quotes ... should have checked earlier

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154007/replace-all-double-quotes-with-single-quotes

Comment: If it wasn't in sed... with `tr` you can do `tr '"' "'"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
[ ~]$ echo "'Hello'"|sed "s/'/\"/g"
"Hello"
```

And the reverse :

```
[ ~]$ echo \"Hello\"|sed "s/\"/'/g"
'Hello'
```

Otherwise, you could use `tr` instead of `sed` if you want :

```
[ ~]$ echo \"Hello\"|tr "\"" "'"
'Hello'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use is as:

```
s='abc"def"123'
echo "$s"|sed "s/\"/'/g"

abc'def'123
```

Answer (score 2):

For replacing just one character, you might as well use `tr`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' '"Hello"' | tr \" \'
'Hello'
```

Now I hope you're not using this to somehow “sanitize” some user input...

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 'y/'\''/"/' file
```