# Using sed with quote marks

Tags: bash, sed, zenity

I'm try to get sed to replace a line in /etc/lsb-release, I'm using the following code:

```
x=$( stdbuf -oL /bin/bash \-c '(sudo sed -i "s/DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION=.*/DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION=Linux Lite 2.4/g" /etc/lsb-release && echo "Linux Lite 2.4" | sudo tee /etc/llver && echo "Linux Lite 2.2 LTS \n \l" | sudo tee /etc/issue && sleep 2 )' 2>&1 |
stdbuf -oL sed -n -e '/\[*$/ s/^/# /p' -e '/\*$/ s/^/# /p'|
zenity --progress --title="Updating version information..." --pulsate \
--width=600 --auto-close )
```

I have to use zenity as it is part of a large file. So I want the last line in /etc/lsb-release to show as:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Lite 2.2"
```

with the existing code, it displays as:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION=Linux Lite 2.2
```

So I would like to preserve the quote marks around "Linux Lite 2.2"

Thank you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace all double quotes with single quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154007/replace-all-double-quotes-with-single-quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
x=$( stdbuf -oL /bin/bash \-c '(sudo sed -i "s/DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION=.*/DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION=\"Linux Lite 2.4\"/g" /etc/lsb-release && echo "Linux Lite 2.4" | sudo tee /etc/llver && echo "Linux Lite 2.2 LTS \n \l" | sudo tee /etc/issue && sleep 2 )' 2>&1 |
stdbuf -oL sed -n -e '/\[*$/ s/^/# /p' -e '/\*$/ s/^/# /p'|
zenity --progress --title="Updating version information..." --pulsate \
--width=600 --auto-close )
```

Relevant bit:

```
#                                                  vv              vv
'... "s/DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION=.*/DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION=\"Linux Lite 2.4\"/g" ...'
```